# Concatenate String from BufferedReader and Pass to UI Thread

Tags: java, android, sockets

First off, this is my first Android/Java sockets project! Take a look at the method below. My goal is to receive multi-line text (actually xml in a wrapper) from a socket connection. I am trying to read each line and concatenate it to a string and pass it back to the messageReceived method for further processing. The reading and concatenation is working just fine however the code never executes beyond the s = mBufferIn.readLine() while loop? If I set a breakpoint on the conditional testing the value of mServerMessage, it never gets this far, even though mServerMessage contains everything that has been sent from the server. If I remove the while loop and set the value of mServerMessage to that of mBufferIn.readLine(), each line is sent to the UI thread successfully but I need to have the entire packet sent  to the messageReceived method at once. What must I do to get this corrected?

**Update**

I have modified the while loop in the run() method to check for the end of the message as per the suggestion below. This is working as it should as the concatenation stops when the ETX char is found in the message however the IF conditional is never executed. Could this have something to do with the AsyncTask? I have posted my ConnectTask class that resides within the MainActivity task as this is how I am connecting to the socket.

**MainActivity**

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //implement the messageReceived method
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //do something with received message
    }
}
```

**TcpClient Class**

```
public void run() {
    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {
            mBufferOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (mRun) {
                String s;
                while ((s = mBufferIn.readLine()) != null && s.indexOf(ETX) < 0) {
                   mServerMessage += s;
                }

                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }
            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set your breakpoint before the troublesome `while` loop and step through it?

Comment: Each line is concatenated to mServerMessage as it should.

Comment: And you eventually exit the `while` loop when you're stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: See my updates above.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a loop where the stop condition is that `.readLine()` is `null`. This is obviously not happening, because each time you read a line from the remote server it's having some content (which differs from `null`), so you won't get out of the loop ever.

There are several ways of achieving what you want:

- One of them would be sending an "EOF" message from the remote server (if you can), for example, sending a `String` which would be "Hey, I'm done and now you have to stop". Then change your loop to be:

  ```
  while (!(s = mBufferIn.readLine().equals("Hey, I'm done and now you have to stop"))) { ... }
  ```
- Another one would be leaving the loop as is and instead of appending the content read on each line, call a method (say, `processString(s)`), that would start a `Thread` and sent the content to the main `Activity`. So is valid for an `Intent`, a `BroadcastReceiver`, etc. This way you won't be blocking the execution of the rest of the loop and process the strings as they are got.

Comment: Thanks for the response nKn, I know that the that the last line will contain </packet> however, this: while (!(s = mBufferIn.readLine().equals("</packet>"))) {} will not compile. I receive: operator ! cannot be applied to java.lang.String

Comment: Ok, so I dug into the server documentation and the message will end in a char '\u0003'. How can I check for a char to break out of the loop?

Comment: If the first line doesn't compile, you can leave it as it is and add a condition below, `if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == '\u0003') { break; }`

Comment: Please see the update to my original post, I overcame this and the while loop is functioning properly but for some reason the if statement after the while loop still does not get executed?

Comment: If \u0003 is the last char sent than readLine() will never read is as then there has to be yet a \n behind. Or the server should close the connection.

Comment: It's just an example to illustrate how to face it, it's not the definitive solution as I'm not doing this application and I really don't know what kind of data is sent - the OP will have to play around to get what he wants, but that's the idea.